# Logistic Regression PySpark MLlib issue with multiple labels

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to create a LogisticRegression model (LogisticRegressionWithSGD), but its getting an error of

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Input validation failed.
```

If I give it binary input (0,1 instead of 0,1,2) it does succeed.

example input:

```
parsed_data = [LabeledPoint(0.0, [4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2]),
LabeledPoint(0.0, [5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4]),
LabeledPoint(1.0, [6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4]),
LabeledPoint(0.0, [4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2]),
LabeledPoint(2.0, [4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2])]
```

Code:
    `model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(parsed_data)`

Is the Logistic Regression model in spark supposed to be for binary classification only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not clear from the documentation (you have to dig in to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L361) to realize it), `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` works only with binary data; for multinomial regression, you should use `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`:

```
 from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel, LogisticRegressionWithSGD
 from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
 parsed_data = [LabeledPoint(0.0, [4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2]),
                LabeledPoint(0.0, [5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4]),
                LabeledPoint(1.0, [6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4]),
                LabeledPoint(0.0, [4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2]),
                LabeledPoint(2.0, [4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2])]     

 model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(parsed_data)) # gives error:
 # org.apache.spark.SparkException: Input validation failed.

 model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(sc.parallelize(parsed_data), numClasses=3)  # works OK
```

Comment: Thanks! I do am getting another issue. After model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(sc.parallelize(parsed_data), numClasses=3)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Apologies, the error was something to do with LabeledPoint. Figured it out :) (can't index LabeledPoint as numpy arrays).  The previous comment was truncated for some reason.

Comment: Does this will work when features vector is sparse vector? I am trying but getting the following error: `model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingData, numClasses=5)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 381, in train
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'features'`, I checked the trainingData type it is `<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>`

Comment: For more details what I have tried with sparse feature vector, please check this [question](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13673/logistic-regression-as-multiclass-classification-using-pyspark-and-issues)

Comment: I have added full error log with details of source code at my [github repo](https://github.com/krishnaiitd/LogisticRegression)